# Find missing element by comparing 2 arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

For some reason I'm having some serious difficulty wrapping my mind around this problem. I need this JS function that accepts 2 arrays, compares the 2, and then returns a string of the missing element. E.g. Find the element that is missing in the currentArray that was there in the previous array.

```
function findDeselectedItem(CurrentArray, PreviousArray){

var CurrentArrSize = CurrentArray.length;
var PrevousArrSize = PreviousArray.length;

// Then my brain gives up on me...
// I assume you have to use for-loops, but how do you compare them??

return missingElement;

}
```

Thank in advance! I'm not asking for code, but even just a push in the right direction or a hint might help...

Comment: You need to compare each element of array A to each element of array B. There a ways to speed up the process though if you know which kind of values you are comparing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work. You should also consider the case where the elements of the arrays are actually arrays too. The indexOf might not work as expected then.

```
function findDeselectedItem(CurrentArray, PreviousArray) {

   var CurrentArrSize = CurrentArray.length;
   var PreviousArrSize = PreviousArray.length;

   // loop through previous array
   for(var j = 0; j < PreviousArrSize; j++) {

      // look for same thing in new array
      if (CurrentArray.indexOf(PreviousArray[j]) == -1)
         return PreviousArray[j];

   }

   return null;

}
```

Comment: doesnt work when we have duplicate entries say previousArray=[5,5,7,7] and currentArray=[5,7,7]..returns null then

Answer (score 31):

Problem statement:

> Find the element that is missing in the currentArray that was there in the previous array.

```
previousArray.filter(function(x) {  // return elements in previousArray matching...
    return !currentArray.includes(x);  // "this element doesn't exist in currentArray"
})
```

(This is as bad as writing two nested for-loops, i.e. O(N<sup>2</sup>) time*). This can be made more efficient if necessary, by creating a temporary object out of `currentArray`, and using it as a hashtable for O(1) queries. For example:)

```
var inCurrent={}; currentArray.forEach(function(x){ inCurrent[x]=true });
```

So then we have a temporary lookup table, e.g.

```
previousArray = [1,2,3]
currentArray = [2,3];
inCurrent == {2:true, 3:true};
```

Then the function doesn't need to repeatedly search the currentArray every time which would be an O(N) substep; it can instantly check whether it's in currentArray in O(1) time. Since `.filter` is called N times, this results in an O(N) rather than O(N<sup>2</sup>) total time:

```
previousArray.filter(function(x) {
    return !inCurrent[x]
})
```

Alternatively, here it is for-loop style:

```
var inCurrent = {};
var removedElements = []
for(let x of currentArray)
    inCurrent[x] = true;
for(let x of previousArray)
    if(!inCurrent[x])
        removedElements.push(x)
        //break; // alternatively just break if exactly one missing element
console.log(`the missing elements are ${removedElements}`)
```

Or just use modern data structures, which make the code much more obvious:

```
var currentSet = new Set(currentArray);
return previousArray.filter(x => !currentSet.has(x))
```

*(sidenote: or technically, as I illustrate here in the more general case where >1 element is deselected, O(M*N) time)

Comment: This is a fabulous answer; gotta love functional programming. Some more work is needed to get it working in non JS1.6 browsers though. Luckily Mozilla has done that work for us in the compatibility sections here: [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and here: [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Strangely enough, while this answer is the nicest, I've got the missing element by returning it when checking for element === -1, not !== -1:
In ES6: previousArray.filter(prev => currentArray.indexOf(prev) === -1

Comment: @JeanmichelCote: ah whoops, I'm amazed no one caught that in four years... I misread the problem to think that the element was missing from the wrong array. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at underscore `difference` function: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#difference

Comment: Wow that's great, what does it return though? An array or a single string variable?

Comment: @DeanGrobler: `=> [1, 3, 4]` looks like an array. Why would you want a string? You can convert an array to a string easily anyways.

Comment: @Felix Kling - That sounds right yes, just wanted to make sure. Thanks :-)

Comment: It returns an array. If you've got only one missing element you probably want to use it `_.difference(CurrentArray,PreviousArray)[0]`. P.S. underscore is a great library. I use it in almost every project. Give it a try.

Comment: Name has been changed to `lodash` and you can find it here: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceBy. Works great for obj arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is code but try to see the difference examples to understand the way:

```
var current = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    prev = [1, 2, 4],
    isMatch = false,
    missing = null;

var i = 0, y = 0,
    lenC = current.length,
    lenP = prev.length;

for ( ; i < lenC; i++ ) {
    isMatch = false;
    for ( y = 0; y < lenP; y++ ) {
        if (current[i] == prev[y]) isMatch = true;
    }
    if ( !isMatch ) missing = current[i]; // Current[i] isn't in prev
}

alert(missing);
```

---

Or using [ECMAScript 5 indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var current = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    prev = [1, 2, 4],
    missing = null;

var i = 0,
    lenC = current.length;

for ( ; i < lenC; i++ ) {
    if ( prev.indexOf(current[i]) == -1 ) missing = current[i]; // Current[i] isn't in prev
}

alert(missing);
```

And with while

```
var current = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    prev = [1, 2, 4],
    missing = null,
    i = current.length;

while(i) {
    missing = ( ~prev.indexOf(current[--i]) ) ? missing : current[i];
}

alert(missing);
```

Comment: Using this we can not get all missing elements.

Answer (score -1):

This is my approach(works for duplicate entries too):-
//here 2nd argument is actually the current array

```
function(previousArray, currentArray) {
    var hashtable=[]; 

    //store occurances of elements in 2nd array in hashtable
    for(var i in currentArray){
        if(hashtable[currentArray[i]]){
            hashtable[currentArray[i]]+=1; //add 1 for duplicate letters
        }else{
            hashtable[currentArray[i]]=1; //if not present in hashtable assign 1
        }
    }
    for(var i in previousArray){
            if(hashtable[previousArray[i]]===0 || hashtable[previousArray[i]] === undefined){ //if entry is 0 or undefined(means element not present)
                return previousArray[i]; //returning the missing element
            }
    else{
             hashtable[previousArray[i]]-=1; //reduce count by 1
        }

    }
}
```

Logic is that i have created a blank array called hashtable. We iterate currentArray first and use the elements as index and values as counts starting from 1(this helps in situations when there are duplicate entries). Then we iterate through previousArray and look for indexes, if they match we reduce the value count by 1. If an element of 2nd array doesnt exist at all then our undefined check condition fires and we return it. If duplicates exists, they are decremented by 1 each time and when 0 is encountered, that elment is returned as missing element.