# Trying to detect if one array is missing elements of another

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have the following code which compares array1 to array2 in order to determine if array1 is missing a value from array2:

```
var array1 = ['bob', 'george'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank'];
var isMissing = false;

console.log(missing(array1, array2));

function missing(a,b) { 
    if (a > b) {
        var length = a.length;
    } else if (b > a) {
        var length = b.length;  
    } else {
        var length = a.length;    
    }

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
    if (b.indexOf(a[i]) == -1) {
         isMissing = true;
    } else {
         isMissing = false;        
    }

    if (isMissing == 'true') {
    break;
    }
}

return isMissing;
}
```

The above doesn't always work though. See below chart for scenarios and results vs expected results:

```
var array1 = ['bob', 'george'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank']; // result:true, expected: true

var array1 = ['bob', 'frank'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank']; // result:true, expected: true

var array1 = ['frank', 'george'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank']; // result:true, expected: true

var array1 = ['frank', 'bob', 'george'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank']; // result:false, expected: false

var array1 = ['frank', 'george', 'sue', 'frank'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank'];  // result:false, expected: true

var array1 = ['frank', 'george', 'sue', 'frank'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank', 'janet'];  // result:false, expected: true

var array1 = ['frank', 'george'];
var array2 = ['frank', 'frank']; // result: false, expected: true
```

I'm not sure what the issue is...

I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736804/find-missing-element-by-comparing-2-arrays-in-javascript) but it isn't bearing any fruit for me since I don't need to know which element is missing, I just need to know if there is one missing.

No external libraries please. thanks.

Comment: @CertainPerformance because if something is missing it should say True, not False, as is the case in all the other examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function missing(array1, array2) {
  const copy = array1.slice()
  return array2.some(element => {
    const index = copy.indexOf(element)
    if(index >= 0) copy.splice(index, 1);
    return index < 0
  })
}


var array1 = ['bob', 'george'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank'];

console.log(missing(array1, array2))

var array1 = ['bob', 'frank'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank'];

console.log(missing(array1, array2))

var array1 = ['frank', 'george'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank'];

console.log(missing(array1, array2))

var array1 = ['frank', 'bob', 'george'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank'];

console.log(missing(array1, array2))

var array1 = ['frank', 'george', 'sue', 'frank'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank'];

console.log(missing(array1, array2))

var array1 = ['frank', 'george', 'sue', 'frank'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank', 'janet'];
console.log(missing(array1, array2))

var array1 = ['frank', 'george'];
var array2 = ['frank', 'frank'];
console.log(missing(array1, array2))
```

Comment: @Sweepster  scenario 5 misses 'bob'

Comment: if array 1 contains 'frank', 'george' and array2 contains 'frank', 'frank' expected result should be true. I'm getting false.

Comment: You answered before me though, If this is the right answer, yours should be accepted

Comment: but the 2nd frank in array 2 is missing from array 1, therefore the result should be true

Comment: @Sweepster check it out

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Make a copy of the first array, then iterate over the elements of the second array, and find the element in the first array, if it is found, remove it so it won't be counted twice.

```js
const missing = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const left = [...arr1];
  return arr2.some(x => {
    const idx = left.indexOf(x);
    if (idx >= 0) left.splice(idx, 1);
    return idx < 0;
  });
}
  
console.log(missing(['bob', 'george'], ['bob', 'george', 'frank'])); // true
console.log(missing(['bob', 'frank'], ['bob', 'george', 'frank'])); // true
console.log(missing(['frank', 'george'], ['bob', 'george', 'frank'])); // true
console.log(missing(['frank', 'bob', 'george'], ['bob', 'george', 'frank'])); // false
console.log(missing(['frank', 'george', 'sue', 'frank'], ['bob', 'george', 'frank']));  // true
console.log(missing(['frank', 'george', 'sue', 'frank'], ['bob', 'george', 'frank', 'janet'])); // true
console.log(missing(['frank', 'george'], ['frank', 'frank'])); // false
```

Comment: @Sweepster, I see you updated your question, my answer should work

Comment: @jo_va our answers are the same

Comment: if array 1 contains 'frank', 'george' and array2 contains 'frank', 'frank' expected result should be true because the 2nd frank is missing in array 1. I'm getting false.

Comment: @Sweepster ok, wait

Comment: @jo_va are you laughing? ahah

Comment: @AlexOwl, haha, not at all, I just saw you updated your code when you posted this comment

Comment: @jo_va is it ok to splice(-1, 1) ?

Comment: @AlexOwl, I think you know the answer, no it is not, haha, it will remove at the end

Comment: @jo_va try to run your snippet, you broke something

Comment: @AlexOwn, well I messed up indeed!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a hard time understanding how you wanted the second last test to be false, but looks like you updated it

```js
console.log(missing(['bob', 'george'], ['bob', 'george', 'frank']) === true);
console.log(missing(['bob', 'frank'], ['bob', 'george', 'frank']) === true); 
console.log(missing(['frank', 'george'], ['bob', 'george', 'frank']) === true);
console.log(missing(['frank', 'bob', 'george'], ['bob', 'george', 'frank']) === false); 
console.log(missing(['frank', 'george', 'sue', 'frank'], ['bob', 'george', 'frank']) === true);
console.log(missing(['frank', 'george', 'sue', 'frank'], ['bob', 'george', 'frank', 'janet']) === true);
console.log(missing(['frank', 'george'], ['frank', 'frank']) === true);

function missing(a, b) {
  var c = [].concat(a); // non-destructive
  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    var iO = c.indexOf(b[i]);
    if (iO < 0) {
      return true;
    }
    c.splice(iO, 1)
  }
  return false;
}
```

the function, because you only care about what's NOT in array `b`, you loop over b and compare to array `a`, as soon as a missing item is found return true right away
otherwise return false at the end

updated to keep track of count

Comment: yah, sorry about that.

Comment: if array 1 contains 'frank', 'george' and array2 contains 'frank', 'frank' expected result should be true because the 2nd frank is missing. I'm getting false.

Comment: ok, that changes things a bit, because it means you need to keep count of items missing

Answer (score 0):

Find first element in second array and remove it.

```
function missing(a,b) {
  let coppied = [...b];
  a.forEach(el => {
    const index = coppied.indexOf(el);
    if (index != -1) {
      coppied.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });

  return !!coppied.length; //If not empty return true
}
```

Comment: this doesn't help when there are repeated values. if one array has two of the same value, then the second should also have 2...

Comment: Check it out now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function missing(a,b){
  //remove duplicated elements
  var aa=a.filter(function(elem, index, self) {return index ===self.indexOf(elem);});
  var bb=b.filter(function(elem, index, self) {return index ===self.indexOf(elem);});
  //put in aa the longest array
  if(aa.length<bb.length){
    var tmp=aa;
    aa=bb;
    bb=tmp;
  }
  var result=false;
  //search for an aa's element not in bb
  aa.forEach(el=>{
    if(bb.indexOf(el)<0){
      result=true;
      return;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

var array1 = ['bob', 'george'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank']; // result:true, expected: true
console.log(missing(array2, array1));

var array1 = ['bob', 'frank'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank']; // result:true, expected: true
console.log(missing(array2, array1));

var array1 = ['frank', 'george'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank']; // result:true, expected: true
console.log(missing(array2, array1));

var array1 = ['frank', 'bob', 'george'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank']; // result:false, expected: false
console.log(missing(array2, array1));

var array1 = ['frank', 'george', 'sue', 'frank'];
var array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank'];  // result:false, expected: true
console.log(missing(array2, array1));

array1 = ['frank', 'george', 'sue', 'frank'];
array2 = ['bob', 'george', 'frank', 'janet'];  // result:false, expected:true
console.log(missing(array2, array1));
```